# Use amsmath x in text

Tags: symbols, amsmath

Probably an easy one but I fail to figure out what the x that amsmath produces in equations is called so I can't figure out how to use it in text. I want to do something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
some equation that uses x_1
\end{equation}
where x$_{\text{1}}$ = something
```

I figured out how to do the subscripts in text but when I run the program, the x from the equation part looks vastly different than the x in text. Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `$x_1$` for inline math. `\text` is used to put normal text in math formula.

Comment: `$x_1=something$` or better `$x_1=\text{something}$`

Answer (score 4):

This is a possible solution between many attemps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\text{some equation that uses } x_1
\end{equation}
where $x_1=$ something.   
\end{document}
```

Comment: comments suggested this solution already

Comment: @user177954 So what? Comments are not answers.

Comment: @egreg It's rude to just use the ideas of other people without giving credit to them. The correct thing to do would be to ask them first if they want to answer.

Comment: @user177954 I disagree; comments might disappear at any time. Besides, this is very basic knowledge of TeX, no credit is necessary. And you don't vote manners, but usefulness of an answer. Flag, if you deem that an answer is violating conduct rules, but don't downvote just for this.

Comment: @user177954: I agree here with egreg. Please stop this nitpicking about these trivial things, especially against always the same user. Comments are actually not for (almost-)answers and the habit of posting these are a TeX.SE specific thing which is totally uncommon on other SE sites. CarLaTeX should have just posted it as an answer.